# AVG 11 Free Doesn't Install

Tags: installation, avg-antivirus, windows-xp

Trying to install AVG free 11, but it gets to the copying files stage and comes up with about 10 'encountered an error' dialogs and then uninstalls.

Running XP SP3. Any ideas? Was running avg free 9 without a problem.

Here is the error information:

```
Severity: Error

Error code: 0xC007060643

Error message: Fatal error during installation.

Additional message: MSI Engine; Failed ot install the product.

Context: @MFAProductInstallation
```

Comment: Obvious first thing to check - have you redownloaded and tried again, in case of a broken installer.

Comment: Maybe a virus is blocking the installation? I'm sure the virus writers know that the best defense is a good offense.

Answer (score -1):

Use MSE instead, it is much better and is Free also.

http://www.microsoft.com/security_essentials/

.

Comment: not really a solution to the question posted :|

Comment: It is a solution, just not the one you want, sorry.

Comment: I agree.  Use MSE.  AVG is full of sneaky stuff like their toolbar etc, which hijacks your browser and scans your requests etc. A increasing problem with free software I suppose.